# vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 90 seconds

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been running multiple unit tests in multiple solutions for years.  Now, out of seemingly nowhere, every time I try to run a unit test, I get this message in the Tests Output pane:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException:
> vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 90
> seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set
> environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.

I've tried restarting VS2019, using it in Admin mode, and restarting my computer. I've tried multiple unit tests in different repos that I know worked.  All fail to run.  I searched around and all of the posts are older and are with people migrating from VS2017 to VS2019 and how they needed to install nuget packages.  I have Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk, MSTest.TestAdapter, MSTest.TestFramework, and coverlet.collector all installed.

Coworkers have pulled the code down and the unit tests run and work fine for them.  There has to have been some update or change that is preventing this from working.  This just started a few days ago.

Comment: Just run into exactly this problem. Unit tests were working in VisualStudio2017; I think that installing VisualStudio2022 has caused this problem.

Comment: I actually ran into the issue prior to installing VS2022.  I installed it hoping that it would fix the issue, but it did not.

Comment: I also have this problem with `net6.0` test projects in VisualStudio2022.

Comment: Not even working from the command line with `dotnet test`. It complains" `vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 90 seconds`.

Comment: Reported to MS https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vstestconsole-process-failed-to-connect/1612516

Answer (score 3):

My issue was caused by an update to our company's VPN.  Disabling the VPN, I was able to run unit tests again.  If you are running into this issue as well, it is likely caused by a VPN/firewall change.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue in Visual Studio 2019. I tried admin/non-admin, restarting, re-installing and upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 without success.

After playing around for a while I found that my issue was caused by split-tunnelling in ExpressVPN which I had set up to allow connections using my actual IP to an Azure SQL database.

To resolve, I disabled the split-tunnelling feature of the VPN and restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had this message for XUnit tests project in VS 2022:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 450 seconds.

I have created MSTest tests project and launched it and it has worked. Then my XUnit tests project started working as well. Magic

Comment: Same problem for me, my firewall was blocking vstest.console

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was VS2022 and help came from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-resolve-issue-of-test-project-not-running-the-unit-tests-after-upgrade-to/ Namely installing "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" which does not make sense, because my test project is XUnit one, and this nuget package is for MS tests, yet it was exactly the missing ingredient.